# Slow Android Device Detection on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows

I work at a company that programs for Android devices.  As such, I connect and have connected hundreds of Android devices to my computer.  Each time I connect a new device (which can be the same model as another device that I had previously connected) Windows runs the Driver Software Installation process.

When I first got this computer it would take about a minute to detect the device.  Maybe a little longer the very first time, but not too long.

Now, after hundreds of devices have been connected to push software to them, the Driver Software Installation dialog takes about 20 minutes to detect one device.

Is there a way to speed this process up at all?  I looked online and have uninstalled all the Android drivers for old devices under Device Manager, but even after uninstalling them all it still takes about 20 minutes to detect one device.

Thanks for any help or insight as to fix this issue.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

There are these drivers available for each company like Motorola, samsung etc for android. You need to install just all the available i.e. on driver for all samsung one for all motorola. That way you could just start off as soon as you plug-in. Just google for motorola driver android , you'll get it.

Comment: And may be probably you are connecting hundreds of such devices it may be the reason to the delay of the process. Depends on the system you are using too.

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab's, the 7" version.  The first thing I did when I got this computer was install the mobile drivers from Samsung, the first time around they were detecting pretty quickly.  But now, after hundreds of devices have been connected to the computer it takes much, much longer to detect a device.

Comment: What are the hundreds of devices? And what is you computer multicored?

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab's, the 7" version. I have a dual core, 2.2GHz i7. I get that they are slow now because I've attached many devices in the past, but I'm trying to find the solution to speed it up.  Not having attached the devices to the computer isn't an option, as it has already been done. My question is how to return the speed to what it was.  I assume the drivers for the older devices are still in memory somewhere, but after uninstalling all of the Android ADB drivers from Device Manager the detection process is still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a driver bug. I tried different Android phones in many computers with windows XP, 7, and 8 and the connection process is very slow in all of them, you have to live with it.